# how to split space java

Tags: java

Guys I need your help for below query ---- 
I have string as follows :

```
"Symbol Exchange    Security Type   Mid Extraction time Net Change  Last price  Bid price   Ask price"
```

I want to split it as below

```
"Symbol,Exchange,Security Type,Mid,Extraction time,Net Change,Last price,Bid price,Ask price"
```

Please help to resolve below query as `split(\\s+)` is not giving the desired solution!

Comment: You can't do that with regex, as your split criteria is not consistent. You are o your own now.

Comment: And how does the code decide which spaces _not_ to split on?

Comment: its been mentioned in the spec as that this how I need to do... its strange as spaces pattern is inconsitent..

Comment: gaps are tabs, String newSentence = sentence.replace('\t', ','); this resolves my query! anyway Thanks guys for your help ! :)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the gaps are tabs:

```
String sentence = "Symbol Exchange    Security Type   Mid Extraction time Net Change  Last price  Bid price   Ask price";

String newSentence = sentence.replace('\t', ',');
```

[reference:  `String.replace()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28char,%20char%29)

Comment: Thanks a ton brother! yeah gaps are tabs! God bless u!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this:

```
String s = "Your source string";
String m = s.replace(" ", ",");
```

Try it.

Comment: gaps are tabs, 
String newSentence = sentence.replace('\t', ',');
this resolves my query! any Thanks for your help bro! :)

Comment: ok, at first without code formatting, it looked like a single space.